# How get spinner item position from Fragment to some Class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

I have some dummy problem, I need to get Spinner Item Position from the Fragment to this class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import com.example.nortti.politrange.R;
import com.example.nortti.politrange.intefaces.ICatalog;
import com.example.nortti.politrange.objects.Person;
import com.example.nortti.politrange.objects.Site;
import com.example.nortti.politrange.utils.WebApiAdapter;
import com.example.nortti.politrange.views.GeneralFragment;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class PersonCatalog implements ICatalog{
    private final String COMMAND_PREFIX = "/api/stats/1";
    private final WebApiAdapter apiAdapter = new WebApiAdapter(COMMAND_PREFIX);
    private ArrayList<Person> catalogList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    private  Site site;

public PersonCatalog(Site site) {
    this.site = site;
}


@Override
public ArrayList<Person> getCatalogList() {
    return catalogList;
}

public void populateData() {
    JSONArray jsonObject = null;

    try {
        jsonObject = (JSONArray)(new JSONParser()).parse(apiAdapter.select(null));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catalogList.clear();
    Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsonObject.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject o = iterator.next();
        catalogList.add(new Person((String)o.get("personName"),(int)(long)o.get("rank")));
    }

}
}
```

I broke my head, I don't know how to do it. Please help! Should I use some Intents or create some getters?

UPD: Fragment Code

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.example.nortti.politrange.R;
import com.example.nortti.politrange.adapters.GenAdapter;
import com.example.nortti.politrange.adapters.SiteAdapter;
import com.example.nortti.politrange.intefaces.ICatalog;
import com.example.nortti.politrange.intefaces.impls.PersonCatalog;
import com.example.nortti.politrange.intefaces.impls.SitesCatalog;
import com.example.nortti.politrange.objects.Site;

public class GeneralFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {

private Button genApply;
private Spinner spinner;
private ListView genList;
private View header;
private ICatalog siteCatalogImpl;
private ICatalog personCatalogImpl;
public int Num;

public void setSpinnerSource(ICatalog siteCatalogImpl) {
    this.siteCatalogImpl = siteCatalogImpl;
    spinData();
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.general_fragment, container,false);

    header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gen_head, null);

    spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.wSpin);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    genApply = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.genApply);
    genApply.setOnClickListener(this);

    genList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.genList);
    genList.addHeaderView(header);
    this.setSpinnerSource(new SitesCatalog());
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("spin", spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
    return v;
}

private void spinData() {
    siteCatalogImpl.populateData();
    spinner.setAdapter(new SiteAdapter(getActivity(), siteCatalogImpl.getCatalogList()));
}

private void listData(Site site) {
    personCatalogImpl = new PersonCatalog(site);
    personCatalogImpl.populateData();
    genList.setAdapter(new GenAdapter(getActivity(), personCatalogImpl.getCatalogList()));
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int siteIndex = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.genApply:
           listData((Site)siteCatalogImpl.getCatalogList().get(siteIndex));
            break;
    }
}
}
```

I calling PersonCatalog at the listdata method.

Comment: how did you call this class from fragment.

Comment: please post fragment code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 final ArrayList<String> providerlist= new ArrayList<String>();
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.prospin);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, providerlist);

adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1); 
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        // On selecting a spinner item 
        String item = providerlist.get(position);

        // Showing selected spinner item 
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Selected Country : " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    } 
});
```

Comment: i know how to put a variable of spinner item position, i don't now how to get it to another class (not Fragment). Thanks